# bernina motor capacitor exploded. How to repair motor

Tags: capacitor, motor

My girlfriends Bernina sewing machine exploded and catched fire. It made a lot of smoke, probably wasnt very healthy. Now what the bernina store said was to get a replacement motor but that also means to get another foot pedal and the 60's sewing machine comes with a very good pedal and (silent) motor.

Now i wonder where I can find a specific capacitator like this.And if we change the capacitator is there a high probability the machine will just work?

Maybe somebody also knows why it exploded? As it has served good for a really long time.. Might it have something to do that the capacitator was calculated for 220v instead of 230v

[image: capacitator side2]

[image: view of broken capacitator]

I can post only two links, the other information (or rubbish) given on the machine is:

capacitator:
leclanche fo= 2/3,5MHz 6O0O    O65   285160

motor:
Scintilla SA 
type HG/NMB 220v 50Hz 
75/32Watt 5700/min 
45/15Watt 3500/min 
(made in switzerland)

any help is welcome!

greets
d

Comment: You need to put a bit more research effort in before asking such a  repair question. Like searching eBay.co.uk for "Bernina motor capacitor" and looking at the first hit.

Comment: Does the motor run without the capacitor?  It doesn't seem like it's a Start or Run capacitor